# How to write a wrapper class that contains multiple workers in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a couple of classes that have the same methods but do things slightly different (`WorkerOne`, `WorkerTwo`). Those classes inherit from an abstract base class using the abc module and `@abstractmethod` annotation for the methods that should be implemented in `WorkerOne` and `WorkerTwo`.

Note: The actual question comes at the end.

Here's the shortened code:

```py
class AbstractWorker(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @abstractmethod
    def log_value(self, value):
        pass


class WorkerOne(AbstractWorker):

    def log_value(self, value):
        # do something differently

class WorkerTwo(AbstractWorker):

    def log_value(self, value):
        # do something differently
```

This works fine and I can create objects for both worker classes and execute the functions accordingly.

E.g.

```py
worker_one = WorkerOne()
worker_two = WorkerTwo()

worker_one.log_value(1)
worker_two.log_value('text')
```

Please note that this is simplified. Each worker uses a different package to track experiments in the ML field and not just differentiates between int and str.

I've been trying to find a way to not call both objects every single time I want to log something. I want to unify these methods in some sort of wrapper class that takes those two objects, and executes the method called on that wrapper, on each object. I call that wrapper a hive as it contains it workers.

Currently, I see two solutions to this but both are lacking quality. The first would be the easier one but results in duplication of code. It is simple and it works but it doesn't follow the DRY principle.

### Solution #1:

```py
class HiveSimple(AbstractWorker):
    def __init__(self, workers: List[AbstractWorker]):
        self.workers = workers

    def log_value(self, value):
        for worker in self.workers:
            worker.log_value(value)
    ...
```

The idea is to have the wrapper/hive class to inherit from the abstract class as well, so we are forced to implement the functions. The workers are passed as a `list` for creating the object. For the `log_value` function we would iterate through the list of workers and execute their own implementation of that method. The problem, as shortly mentioned, is 1) duplicated code and 2) the hive class also grows or needs to be altered when a new method is added to the abstract base class.

The second solution is a bit more advanced and avoids duplicated code but has also a disadvantage.

### Solution #2:

```py
class Hive:

    def __init__(self, trackers: List[AbstractWorker]):
        self.workers = workers
        self._ls_functions = []

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        for worker in self.workers:
            self._ls_functions.append(getattr(worker, name))
        return self.fn_executor

    def fn_executor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for fn in self._ls_functions:
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
        self._ls_functions = []
```

In this solution I make use of the `__getattr__` function. If I call the `log_value()` function on the hive object (`hive.log_value()`) it looks first if it has the `log_value` attribute/function. If the attribute does not exist, it enters the `__getattr__` function and executes the code. There, I iterate through the list of workers and collect the functions with the same `name`. I then return the function `fn_executor`, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to hand over the parameters with which the `log_value()` function was called on the hive object. Although this works fine, the issue is that you need to know the parameters and the types beforehand. Since we don't use inheritance we don't have the advantage of IntelliSense, because the functions are no members of the hive class. Makes sense.

So I wanted to mitigate that by adding functions as attributes during the `__init__`, which works.

#### Solution #2.1:

```py
class Hive:

    def __init__(self, trackers: List[AbstractWorker]):
        self.workers = workers
        self._ls_functions = []

        for fn_name in dir(AbstractWorker):
            if not (fn_name.startswith('__') or fn_name.startswith('_')):
                setattr(self, fn_name, self.fn_wrapper(str(fn_name)))

    def fn_wrapper(self, name):
        def fn(*params, **kwargs):
            return self.__getattr__(name)(*params, **kwargs)
        return fn

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        for worker in self.workers:
            self._ls_functions.append(getattr(worker, name))
        return self.fn_executor

    def fn_executor(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for fn in self._ls_functions:
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
        self._ls_functions = []
```

In solution #2.1 I try to fetch all functions from the abstract base class with `dir(AbstractWorker)`, removing dunder functions and "private" ones with the `if` and set the name of the functions as an attribute. Additionally, I assign a wrapper function (similar to `partial` or a decorator) that contains the `__getattr__` function. During runtime the members are correctly set, but since IntelliSense relies on static code analysis, it is difficult to handle dynamic attribute assignment and as a result IntelliSense refuses to bring them up.

Now to the question:

What would be the best approach to create a wrapper/hive class that knows about the signature of the functions from the abstract base class but gets rid of the duplication of code shown in solution #1?

Comment: In the first example the arguments to the "log_value" methods of the different workers are different but in the solutions all methods receive the same value or arguments. Which is right?

Comment: Since I didn't specify a type hint I just wanted to demonstrate that the first worker handled int values and the second worker a string. Normally, they would receive the same type because the wrapper would only pass it on.

Comment: In that case a better illustrative example would be to have the workers receive the same value but _do different things_, like print the value unchanged vs print the value in uppercase.

Comment: I don't know IntelliSense's behavior but how about using solution #2.1 but deriving "Hive" from "AbstractWorker"?

Comment: This is a good addition, and it works well. The functions are added, but can be left unchanged (by just leaving pass in there) as they are overwritten by the `__init__` function. Thanks for pointing me in that direction. 

I also experimented with a custom metaclass. I added the functions correctly to the metaclass, but IntelliSense does not resolve them. The functions can still be executed on the wrapper and `Hive.__dict__` also shows that they are available, but PyCharm does not show them. Maybe there is a problem with PyCharm's IntelliSense, as I have stumbled across similar requests.